# On the execution of the block of code its skips the character input i.e scanf()

Tags: compiler-errors, char, syntax-error, runtime, scanf

Everytime i try to run the code , the character input statement scanf("%c",&ch); gets totally ignored and jumps to the netx line resulting in the executioon of the infinite while loop ( i made it comment line in the above block). Cant find where i went wrong. Other functions are working properly though.

```
void main()
 {
     int n,g,i;
     char ch;

     printf("Enter the number of students present today\n");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        printf("Enter the rolls of the students who are present\n");
        attendance();
     }

     printf("Enter the state of the student entry/departure\n");
     printf("\n a for Entry and d for departure and c for door close\n");
     scanf("%c",&ch);


     /*while(1)
     {
         switch(ch)
         {
             case 'a':
            printf("Enter the roll of the students who arrived\n");
            entry();
            break;

            case 'd':
            printf("Enter the roll of the student who departed\n");
            departure();
            break;

            case 'c':
            exit(0);

            default:
            printf("Wrong\n");

         }
     }*/
     printf("Want to see the rolls of the student left in class?[1/0]");
     scanf("%d",&g);
     if(g==1)
     display();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `scanf` can be tricky.  To debug problems like this it can be helpful to insert a line after the `scanf` to show you exactly what the result was, something like:

```
    printf("scanf got character '%c' (0x%02x)\n", ch, ch);
```

That will show you the character and the numeric value of that character, which can be helpful if the character is something exotic that doesn't have an easily-recognisable printed appearance.

If you do that in this case it will tell you that `scanf("%c")` gave you the very next character it found, which was a newline character.  That's the newline that was still sitting in the input buffer, left over from the end of the input line that was examined by the previous `scanf` call in your `attendance` function.

If you want `scanf` to skip past leftover whitespace characters, including newlines, then you should put a space at the start of the `scanf` format string.  So change your existing:

```
    scanf("%c",&ch);
```

to

```
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

and that should get you the behaviour you want.